# Array of 3 request functions - how to invoke the second function only if first function's response contains string? - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I have an array of 3 functions that use node-fetch to fetch data from 3 different APIs. I would like to only invoke the second and third function if the first function's response.body contains 'rejected'.

The problem I am running in to is that all the methods are being invoked before the response is received from the first.

```
const buyersList = [
  { buyerName: 'ACME',
    buyerPrice: '100',
    buyerMethod: sellACME,
  },
  { buyerName: 'ACME',
    buyerPrice: '60',
    buyerMethod: sellACME,
  },
  { buyerName: 'ACME',
    buyerPrice: '20',
    buyerMethod: sellACME,
  },
  { buyerName: 'ACME',
    buyerPrice: '2',
    buyerMethod: sellACME,
  },
];

//fetch the data and parse
function sellACME(url) {
  return fetch(url, { method: 'POST' })
  .then(obj => parseResponse(obj))
  .catch(err => console.log(' error', err));
}

//shift the first item in array and execute the method for first item. 
const methods = {};
methods.exBuyerSell = (url) => {
  const currBuyer = buyersList.shift();
  return currBuyer.buyerMethod(url);
};

//loop through array.
module.exports = (url, res) => {
  while (buyersList.length > 0) {
    methods.exBuyerSell(url)
    .then((buyerRes) => {
      //if response.result is accepted, empty array, send response to client. 
      if (buyerRes.result === 'accepted') {
        buyersList.length = 0;
        res.json(buyerRes);
      }
      //if response.result is rejected, execute the next item in array. 
      if (buyerRes.result === 'rejected') {
        methods.exBuyerSell(url);
      }
      return buyerRes;
    });
  }
};
```

The business logic here is that, if the data is transmitted to the first buyer, the data is accepted by that buyer and can not be presented to the second buyer.

setTimeout() is not an option as the array can grow to be as long as 20 and each request can take up to 180 seconds.

I attempted to use async/await and async.waterfall, but still seemed to have the same issue.

Comment: I misunderstood your problem the first time. Please check my updated answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This concept can be applied to your own use case. It will iterate over the collection until the promise resolves:

```
pipePromises([2,4,6,1], calculateOddity).then(res => console.log(res))

function pipePromises(ary, promiser) {
  return ary.slice(1, ary.size).reduce(
    (promise, n) => promise.catch(_ => promiser(n)), 
    promiser(ary[0])
  );
}

function calculateOddity(n) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    n % 2 === 0 ? reject(n) : resolve(n);
  })
}
```